# query about the RAM IC in this picture

Tags: integrated-circuit, ram

Have this ZOOM recorder and it came with 150V power adapter. It got accidently plugged to a 250V and went dead. I opened to see if it can be fixed and found this RAM IC EM638165TS in this condition:

[image: RAM chip with possible damage]

Im just a amateur in this field can't understand if this picture looks normal. The other side there is also a TMS320 which is texas int. DSP but it look smooth surface.

Comment: My first impression was glue. It is a bit hard to make out from the picture whether is something *on* the package or the package *itself* being damaged. Can you describe it in words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance it looks like the plastic package has erupted due to overheating and this may well be the case. However, package eruption is usually very localized over the top of the die. The marks *could* just be glue or some other contaminant but I fear this is just wishful thinking.

If it is (as I suspect) thermal damage then it is unlikely to be the only part damaged and the recorder is no more.

Try to scratch the suface of the IC with a small screwdriver. If pieces of the case flake away leaving pits in the surface of the case, the part is indeed incinerated.